# why "RuntimeError CUDA out of memory" in testing?

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, deep-learning, pytorch

The same [model](https://github.com/chaoyuaw/pytorch-coviar) ran fine for training with batch-size=5. I reduced the batch size from 80 to 5 during training because of the same error. I am using a GPU with 11GB of memory instead of Titan X (12GB memory), the one used by the author in actual experiment.

However, now in testing, which only has batch-size=1, it is not running.

The issue is in `I-frame model` testing phase, the other two models have successfully produced results for testing.

Following is my testing command:

```
time python test.py --arch resnet152 --data-name ucf101 --representation iframe --data-root data/ucf101/mpeg4_videos --test-list data/datalists/ucf101_split1_test.txt --weights ucf101_iframe_model_iframe_model_best.pth.tar --save-scores iframe_score_file
```

I have used `nvidia-smi` to make sure nothing else is running on the GPU.

Following is the actual error message:

```
RuntimeError: CUDA out of memory. Tried to allocate 384.00 MiB (GPU 0; 10.92 GiB total capacity; 10.12 GiB already allocated; 245.50 MiB free; 21.69 MiB cached)
```

What could be the issue and how it can be fixed?

**EDIT**: By removing the following two lines from test.py, it starts running without an memeory issue, but it is taking ages to process:

```
net = torch.nn.DataParallel(net.cuda(devices[0]), device_ids=devices)
net.eval()
```

Yes, the above lines are for GPU based parallel processing.

Still, is there a solution to my problem?

Comment: You could try deleting the variables (which are on GPU) explicitly using `del var_name`. Also, you could use [this `memory_allocated` function](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/cuda.html#torch.cuda.memory_allocated) in your code at different points to see how much memory is allocated at that point. This should help you figure out what part eats up your GPU memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have run this model/testing on GPU with memory upto 8GB, by adding the following flag in the testing command given in the question:

```
--test-crops 1
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you may check your test code first.

You can try:

```
with torch.no_grad():
```

It will reduce memory consumption for computations that would otherwise have requires_grad=True.

*Original Answer(you can try it if you have a bigger GPU):*

*Maybe the model itself and parameters take up a lot of memory.*

*You can try "batch-size=1" on your Titan X GPU which you used before and watch whether GPU memory usage is more than 11 GB. If so, the GPU you use now(11 GB memory) may not suitable for this work.*

Comment: OP says the original author used a Titan X. He only has a 11 GB memory GPU (maybe GTX 1080Ti or something)